# react-router-dom usage in index.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Contact from './Contact';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import RouterMapping from './RouterMapping';
const RouterMapping = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
    <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />

  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <RouterMapping />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When rendering the page `/`, it displays nothing (should go to `App` component per my understanding. The `App` component itself is running OK if I replace:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <RouterMapping />, 
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

to

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <App />, 
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Did I do something fundamentally wrong? Newbie to React...

**Update on Mar 16**

I think I figured out how to make the router work.

I have refactored my `RouterMapping` to `RoutingConfig` as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home';
import Contact from './Contact';

const RoutingConfig = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default RoutingConfig;
```

Nothing peculiar.

Now, instead of rendering `RoutingConfig` in my `index.js`, I still render the `App` component in my `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The routing mapping is done now in `App.js`:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RoutingConfig />
    );
  }
}
```

Now it works. Please see attached screenshot:

[image]

**My explanation**

I think the key here is to demote the `RoutingConfig` to `App.js`. From `index.js` render `App.js`, `App.js` will act as the entry point to my whole app and determine which component (`Home`, `Contact`) to load based on routing.

Above for your information and hope it is helpful.

Comment: try using react-router module than react-router-dom

Comment: Nope... Same issue.

Comment: try to compare with this https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Comment: @JayantPatil You mean I should install react-router-redux too?

Comment: yes try to modify your router and if not then try adding provider

Comment: Will try later if no other inputs.

Comment: Ignore all the advice above as it's irrelevant. Are you getting any errors in your console? Your code looks correct as far as I can tell. Are you using shouldComponentUpdate in App?